# how to map a json object into another new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

i have a  payload response which goes like:

```
"requirementDetails": {
            "requirementId1": "A",
            "requirementId2": "B",
            "requirementId3": "C",
            "requirementId4": "D",
            "requirementId5": "E",
            "requirementId6": "",
            "requirementId7": "",
            "requirementId8": "",
            "requirementId9": "",
        }
```

and i want to create new array of the requirements which will not take the blank requirements using javascript map function and i want the resultant array to look like this:

```
data = [ "A","B","C","D","E"]
```

can anybody please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all values using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and then you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it

```js
const payload = {
  requirementDetails: {
    requirementId1: "A",
    requirementId2: "B",
    requirementId3: "C",
    requirementId4: "D",
    requirementId5: "E",
    requirementId6: "",
    requirementId7: "",
    requirementId8: "",
    requirementId9: "",
  },
};

const data = Object.values(payload.requirementDetails).filter(Boolean);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: what if i want to create new object, instead of array out of the response?

Comment: You should update your question with that new requirement giving an example of your expected output. @mptl